# Google Cloud Storage: bulk edit ACLs

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We are in the process of moving our servers into the Google Cloud Compute Engine and starting to look the Cloud Storage as a CDN option. I uploaded about 1,000 files through the Developer Console but the problem is all the Object Permissions for All Users is set at None. I can't find any way to edit all the permissions to give All Users Reader access. Am I missing something?

Comment: See also [Google Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cdn) – currently in alpha, requires whitelisting for access.

Comment: Just want to point out that, while the accepted solution from Misha might address what the OP is asking for, i.e. to give 'All Users' Read access, the '-g All:R' option actually gives *anyone* on the Internet 'Read' access to your documents. See the acl documentation if you're looking for finer-tooth approaches to granting access.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`gsutil acl ch`](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl#ch) command to do this as follows:

```
gsutil -m acl ch -R -g All:R gs://bucket1 gs://bucket2/object ...
```

where:

- `-m` sets multi-threaded mode, which is faster for a large number of objects
- `-R` recursively processes the bucket and all of its contents
- `-g All:R` grants all users read-only access

See the [`acl` documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl) for more details.

You can use [Google Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-shell/) as your console via a web browser if you just need to run a single command via `gsutil`, as it comes preinstalled in your console VM.

Comment: So there is no way to do this through the web interface? I didnt want to install https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install

Comment: The UI does not provide a bulk edit mode, so given that you have 1000 files, `gsutil` is better for you. Also, note that installing gsutil, whether [by itself](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) or as part of the [Google Cloud SDK](https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/) just requires downloading and decompressing an archive; you don't need root permissions or to install it in `/usr/bin` or modify the system. If that does not address your concerns, I'm curious to hear what the issue is with installing the `gsutil` tool.

Comment: Since I can't edit the previous comment anymore, yes, you can edit permissions through the web UI, but only one file at a time: (1) click on the checkbox next to an object, (2) click on "Object Permissions", and (3) set "All Users" permission to "Reader", or simply click on the checkbox next to "Shared publicly".

For modifying more than a few files, you want to automate this task. You _could_ try writing a Javascript hack to automate checking of the checkbox, but it seems safer and easier to just use `gsutil` for this.

Comment: In addition to what Misha suggested (to change ACLs for existing objects), you might want to consider setting the default object ACLs on the bucket as describe here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#default
That will assign the specified ACLs to each newly uploaded object (unless overridden).

Comment: I deleted the bucket from the web interface, added it again setting the permissions for All Users to read and then used the web interface and uploaded one file. The file did not take the permissions from the bucket like the google docs set. As for installing the Google SDK on my windows computer, it just seems pointless to do this just to edit all the files. I think google should have an online console to run commands. I will go ahead and accept the answer and I will just move the files out of the Cloud Storage and place them somewhere else :-(

Comment: @BradWickwire There isn't a console (which is a good idea!) but you can quickly and easily create one by spinning up the smallest Linux instance on GCE (e.g., I used `f1-micro` with CentOS 6) which will come with `gsutil` preinstalled, run the command(s) you need, shut down, and delete the instance. At the [current price](https://developers.google.com/compute/pricing) for an `f1-micro` of USD$0.013/hr, it should cost less than a penny to do this.

Comment: I just tested Misha's suggestion and it was surprisingly painless. Use `gsutil config` and then copy/paste the oauth stuff and then you're done. Thumbs up!

Comment: **Update:** you can use [Google Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-shell/) as your console via a web browser! @BradWickwire, I think this is what you've been asking about. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using the [`gsutil acl`](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl) command to change the existing ACLs, you can use the [`gsutil defacl`](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/defacl) command to set the default object ACL on the bucket as follows:

```
gsutil defacl set public-read gs://«your bucket»
```

You can then upload your objects in bulk via:

```
gsutil -m cp -R «your source directory» gs://«your bucket»
```

and they will have the correct ACLs set. This will all be much faster than using the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the access control permission by using "predefinedAcl" the code is as follows.

Storage.Objects.Insert insertObject =client.objects().insert(, ,);

```
insertObject.setPredefinedAcl("publicRead");
```

This will work fine

Comment: I ended up using CloudBerry as it allowed me to use an interface to make all edits.

Answer (score 0):

Do not miss to put jolly characters after the bucket's object to apply changes to each files - example:

```
gsutil -m acl ch -R -g All:R gs://bucket/files/*
```

for all files inside the 'files' folder, or:

```
gsutil -m acl ch -R -g All:R gs://bucket/images/*.jpg
```

for each jpg file inside the 'images' folder.